# Render 2 flotgraphs by toggling on click of hyperlink

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, toggle, flot

In my website plotting of Flot Bargraphs is done successfully.On the pageload I am inlcluding 2 bargraphs in div's,with one div style as none.I have a hyperlink on click of that The graph in the div with style none would be visible and the other graph should be invisible.
My code :

Javascript:

```
function abc()
{
    alert("hi");
    document.getElementById('none').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('two').style.display='block';

}
```

PHP Code:

```
<a onclick="abc()" href="#">click me</a>
<div id="one">
<?php include "graphs/newbar.php";?>
</div>

<div id="two" style="display:none">
<?php include "graphs/anotherbarquery.php";?>
</div>
```

when I click the hyperlink,the second graph is invisible.

anotherbarquery.php:

```
<?php require_once('../../Connections/finalkms.php'); ?>
<?php
mysql_select_db($database_finalkms, $finalkms);
$query_get_couunt = "SELECT  EquipmentMainCatagory,count(EquipmentMainCatagory) FROM `assetinfo` group by `EquipmentMainCatagory` HAVING EquipmentMainCatagory <>''";
$get_couunt = mysql_query($query_get_couunt, $finalkms) or die(mysql_error());
$row_get_couunt = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_couunt);
$totalRows_get_couunt = mysql_num_rows($get_couunt);

$rows = array();

while($row_get_couunt = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_couunt))
{
$rows[] = array( $row_get_couunt['EquipmentMainCatagory'],(int)$row_get_couunt['count(EquipmentMainCatagory)']); 
}
// convert data into JSON format
$jsonTable = json_encode($rows);
print_r($jsonTable);    

?>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="../../assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tickrotatotor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="../../assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.labelangle.min.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder1" style="width:900px;height:450px;"></div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        //******* 2012 Average Temperature - BAR CHART
        var data =<?php echo $jsonTable;?>;
        //alert(data);

//var data = [["item1",277],["item2",635],["item3",133]];

var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ticks.push([i,data[i][0]]);
    data[i][0] = i;   
}
alert(ticks);
        //var data = [[0, 11],[1, 15],[2, 25],[3, 24],[4, 13],[5, 18]];
        var dataset = [{ data: data, color: "#5482FF" }];
        //var ticks = [[0, "London"], [1, "New York"], [2, "New Delhi"], [3, "Taipei"],[4, "Beijing"], [5, "Sydney"]];

        var options = {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 5,
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.5,
                    align:"center"
                }
            },
             xaxis: {
                axisLabel: "EquipmentMainCatagory",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 10,
                ticks: ticks,
                //rotateTicks:90
                labelAngle: 90

            },
            yaxis: {
                axisLabel: "# Assets",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 3,                    
            },

            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.plot($("#placeholder1"), dataset, options);
            $("#placeholder1").UseTooltip();
        });

      var previousPoint = null, previousLabel = null;

        $.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
            $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                if (item) {
                    if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                        previousLabel = item.series.label;
                        $("#tooltip").remove();

                        var x = item.datapoint[0];
                        var y = item.datapoint[1];

                        var color = item.series.color;

                        //console.log(item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label);               

                        showTooltip(item.pageX,
                        item.pageY,
                        color,
                      // "<strong>" + y + "</strong>");
         item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>");    
                    }    

                } else {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;
                }
            });
        };

        function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y ,
                left: x,
                border: '2px solid ' + color,
                padding: '3px',
                'font-size': '9px',
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'background-color': '#fff',
                'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                opacity: 0.9
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }
    </script>

<?php
mysql_free_result($get_couunt);
?>
```

newbar.php:

```
<?php

    /* Your Database Name */
    $dbname = 'dbname';

    /* Your Database User Name and Passowrd */
    $username = 'username';
    $password = 'password';

    try {
      /* Establish the database connection */
      $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
      $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

      $result = $conn->query("SELECT  EquipmentMainCatagory,count(EquipmentMainCatagory) FROM `assetinfo` group by `EquipmentMainCatagory` HAVING EquipmentMainCatagory <>''");

      $rows = array();

        foreach($result as $r) {

         $rows[] = array( $r['EquipmentMainCatagory'],(int)$r['count(EquipmentMainCatagory)']); 

        }

    // convert data into JSON format
    $jsonTable = json_encode($rows);

        //print_r($jsonTable);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    //mysql_close($conn);

     $conn=null;

    ?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Flot Bar Chart</title>

<!--<style type="text/css">
body { font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; }
h1 { width: 450px; margin: 0 auto; font-size: 12px; text-align: center; }
#placeholder { width: 450px; height: 200px; position: relative; margin: 0 auto; }
.legend table, .legend > div { height: 82px !important; opacity: 1 !important; right: -55px; top: 10px; width: 116px !important; }
.legend table { border: 1px solid #555; padding: 5px; }
#flot-tooltip { font-size: 12px; font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; position: absolute; display: none; border: 2px solid; padding: 2px; background-color: #FFF; opacity: 0.8; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; -khtml-border-radius: 5px; border-radius: 5px; }
</style>-->

<!--[if lte IE 8]><script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="excanvas.min.js"></script><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript"  src="assets/plugins/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"  src="assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script src="assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.time.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.orderBars.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.tickrotatotor.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.axislabels.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="assets/plugins/flot/jquery.flot.labelangle.min.js"></script>

<div id="placeholder" style="width:900px;height:450px;"></div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
        //******* 2012 Average Temperature - BAR CHART
        var data =<?php echo $jsonTable;?>;
        //alert(data);

//var data = [["item1",277],["item2",635],["item3",133]];

var ticks = [];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ticks.push([i,data[i][0]]);
    data[i][0] = i;   
}
alert(ticks);
        //var data = [[0, 11],[1, 15],[2, 25],[3, 24],[4, 13],[5, 18]];
        var dataset = [{ data: data, color: "#5482FF" }];
        //var ticks = [[0, "London"], [1, "New York"], [2, "New Delhi"], [3, "Taipei"],[4, "Beijing"], [5, "Sydney"]];

        var options = {
            series: {
                lineWidth: 5,
                bars: {
                    show: true,
                    barWidth: 0.5,
                    align:"center"
                }
            },
             xaxis: {
                axisLabel: "EquipmentMainCatagory",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 10,
                ticks: ticks,
                //rotateTicks:90
                labelAngle: 90
            },
            yaxis: {
                axisLabel: "# Assets",
                axisLabelUseCanvas: true,
                axisLabelFontSizePixels: 12,
                axisLabelFontFamily: 'Verdana, Arial',
                axisLabelPadding: 3,                    
            },

            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: { colors: ["#ffffff", "#EDF5FF"] }
            }
        };

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);
            $("#placeholder").UseTooltip();
        });

      var previousPoint = null, previousLabel = null;

        $.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
            $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
                if (item) {
                    if ((previousLabel != item.series.label) || (previousPoint != item.dataIndex)) {
                        previousPoint = item.dataIndex;
                        previousLabel = item.series.label;
                        $("#tooltip").remove();

                        var x = item.datapoint[0];
                        var y = item.datapoint[1];

                        var color = item.series.color;

                        //console.log(item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label);               

                        showTooltip(item.pageX,
                        item.pageY,
                        color,
                      // "<strong>" + y + "</strong>");
         item.series.xaxis.ticks[x].label + " : <strong>" + y + "</strong>");

                    }    

                } else {
                    $("#tooltip").remove();
                    previousPoint = null;
                }
            });
        };

        function showTooltip(x, y, color, contents) {
            $('<div id="tooltip">' + contents + '</div>').css({
                position: 'absolute',
                display: 'none',
                top: y ,
                left: x,
                border: '2px solid ' + color,
                padding: '3px',
                'font-size': '9px',
                'border-radius': '5px',
                'background-color': '#fff',
                'font-family': 'Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, Tahoma, sans-serif',
                opacity: 0.9
            }).appendTo("body").fadeIn(200);
        }
    </script>

</head>

</html>
```

Comment: This because you cannot run php that way.

Comment: can you please elaborate? Goikiu

Comment: Sorry, i've read better, php code is working. your trouble is with Javascript. Have you tried see what happen with console debug?

Comment: @user3171940: You have a Typo: document.getElementById('none').style.display='none'; should actually be document.getElementById('one').style.display='none';

Comment: ya sorry for that typo :( .Even then when  I click the hyperlink The 1st graph is getting disappeared.

Comment: What does `<?php include "graphs/anotherbarquery.php";?>` include?  Can you post that code?

Comment: In your `yaxis` options, you have a `,` after the last property. This can lead to errors in older browsers and should be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flot needs a placeholder with a fixed size to draw the graph. As long as your div with id "two" is invisible, it has no size.

To fix this save your plot object to a variable:

```
var $plot2 = $.plot($("#placeholder"), dataset, options);
```

and draw it after showing the second div by adding this to your `abc` function:

```
$plot2.setupGrid();
$plot2.draw();
```

Comment: thank you Raidri .It worked. I have also done this:            function plotoverall()
    {
            $.plot($("#placeholder1"), dataset, options);
            $("#placeholder1").UseTooltip();
    }                                                      and called that function in abc()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of javascript please jquery . try it

```
$(function() {
    $("a").click( function() {
           $("#one").hide();
           $("#two").show();
      });
});
```

Comment: No Sudharsan I tried that too,On clicking Hyperlinknothing is displayed on my page.